# Is it possible to compress json in hive external table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql, hadoop-streaming

I want to know how to compress json data in hive external table. How can it be done?
I have created external table like this:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
id BIGINT,created_at STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN
)ROW FORMAT SERDE "com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe" LOCATION "/user/cloudera/tweets";
```

and I had set the compression properties

```
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
set io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
```

input file : test

```
{ "id": 596344698102419451, "created_at": "MonApr0101: 32: 06+00002013", "source": "blank", "favorited": false }
```

after that i have load my json file into hdfs location  `"/user/cloudera/tweets".`

but it is not compressed.

Can you please let me know  how to do compression in hive external table ?
Can someone help me to compress in hive external table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just gzip your files and put them as is (*.gz) into the table location

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply .....I have tried and I am able to compress but when I am running an aggregation query on top of external table, I am getting error like "Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT"

Comment: This seems not related to compression. Please check you file. There should be exactly one line per record(json object), without \n inside Json object. Like this line: {"col1":123, "col2":321}\n

Comment: Hi,I have only one record in my json file like : {"id": 596344698102419451, "created_at": "MonApr0101: 32: 06+00002013", "source": "blank", "favorited": false} 
 ,after compression my .GZ file looks like :  0 {"id": 596344698102419451, "created_at": "MonApr0101: 32: 06+00002013", "source": "blank", "favorited": false}

zero adding extra  but when I am running an aggregation query on top of external table,, I am getting error like below

Comment: "Failed with exception ava.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2. SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:   Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1cbf4643; line: 1, column: 1]"

Comment: I have created table: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
id BIGINT,created_at STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE; then I created file with your example string, then gzip file, then hadoop fs -put file.gz table_location;  Ihave succeeded selecting rows

Comment: hive> select * from tweets;
OK
596344698102419451      MonApr0101: 32: 06+00002013     blank   false
Time taken: 4.583 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Comment: Even, I had created table like 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (id BIGINT,created_at STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN)ROW FORMAT SERDE "com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe" LOCATION "/user/cloudera/tweets";

Comment: and then gzip file using  hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar -libjars /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dmap.output.compress=true  -Dmap.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec -Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true -Dmapreduce.output.compress=true  -Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec -input /user/cloudera/json/ -output /user/cloudera/jsonGZ/ , then hadoop fs -put file.gz table_location;

Comment: select * from jsongz;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@fd642e2; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: There are few differences: 1- DDL. I used SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' STORED AS TEXTFILE; 2-gzip. used gzip filename, not hadoop serde (I compressed not in Hadoop, then put into hadoop)

Comment: Hi, are you using cloudera?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114524/discussion-between-leftjoin-and-sai-kumar).

Comment: Now I have used "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.core(hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar)" , after executing all step as you mentioned above.
now I am getting error "Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected"

Comment: HI,can you please let me know why i am getting error like "Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected"  after using "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.core(hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar)"

Comment: Let's discuss this in a chat

Comment: can please let me know how you compressed your input file, can please share command .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support and help it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you need uncompress before you will select it like json. You can't use both serde (json and gzip)